# I want my for-loop to update even when there is no event

Tags: python, loops, events, pynput

```
 while running == True:
     events = get_gamepad()
     for e in events:
         x_add,y_add = translate(e) # translates button pressions into keyboard
                                    # and mouse actions
     mouse.move(x_add,y_add)
```

I'm trying to make a code which gets inputs from my Xbox controller and reproduces a correspondent input from my keyboard and mouse.

The function `translate()`, which is supposed to do so, works fine with buttons but the problem occurs when I try to move my cursor using joysticks: It moves but only when I register a new event moving the stick, if I don't move them and there is no update my loop doesn't cycle, so even if I take the joystick all the way to the max, it doesn't register any new events and my cursor doesn't move.

Comment: `mouse.move(x_add,y_add)` is outside of `for` loop. I think it has to be inside.

Comment: I tried both but the problem is that when the for loop is executed it doesn't continue until an event is registered. Also sorry for my english.

Comment: Try the solution proposed here: https://github.com/zeth/inputs/issues/7